# Обучающие View в приложении

Tags: java, android, view

Хочу спросить как делаются обучающие `View` в приложениях? (Те которые появляются, когда открывается приложение первый раз). И как они правильно называются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть готовые библиотеки, вроде [TourGuide](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide), [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView), [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) и [еще множество](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=showcaseviews).

Самому такое делать несколько трудозатратно, но вы можете посмотреть исходный код этих библиотек.

Закрепленного официального названия за этим инструментом пожалуй нет, но наиболее распространенное *Showcase Screen/View*.